# SwiftUI: Could this be a potential race condition in Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have two functions `add(_:completion:)` and `get(query:completion:)` which I feel may cause errors in my code. Since the `add(_:completion:)` appends a `Book` instance to the `@Published books` property it might cause a race condition with the listener. This is how I imagine it might happen:

1. I add a `book` to the books collection in Firestore using `add(_:completion:)`
2. Once the book is added the listener gets fired and at the **same time** the original `add(_:completion:)` function is about to execute it's completion handler
3. If the `add(_:completion:)` completion handler is executed *before* the `get(query:completion:)` listener block then there will be no issues because the subsequent call to the listener block will just overwrite the `self.books` property by doing `self.books = books`. However, if the `get(query:completion:)` listener block is executed before, then the subsequent execution of the `add(_:completion:)` completion handler will append a duplicate book to the end of the `self.books` property by doing `self.books.append(book)`.

I've marked all the important parts of my code with `//<<< Over here!!!`

```
class BookRepository: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var books = [Book]()
    private var listener: ListenerRegistration?

    func add(_ book: Book, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        let _ = try! db.collection(.books).addDocument(from: book) { error in
            if error == nil { self.books.append(book) }  //<<< (1) Over here!!! Might get called at the same time as (2)
            completion(error)
        }
    }
    func get(query: Query, completion: @escaping (BookError?) -> Void) {
        // Storing listener to single property so multiple calls to get(query:completion:) won't create multiple listeners
        listener = query.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
            var err: BookError?

            // Make sure no network errors
            guard error != nil else { completion(.networkError); return }
            precondition(snapshot != nil, "If there's no error snapshot must exist")
            
            // Convert documents to Book instances
            let documents = snapshot!.documents
            let books = documents.compactMap { try? $0.data(as: Book.self) }
            
            // Check if all documents were successfully decoded and if I didn't try to access an empty collection
            if documents.count != books.count || documents.isEmpty {
                err = documents.isEmpty
                            ? .emptyQuery
                            : .incorrectBookData(self.getBadData(documents, books))  // Retrieves ID's of documents which weren't decoded into Books
            }
            
            // Assign books to the @Published property to update UI
            self.books = books  //<<< (2) Over here!!! Might get called at the same time as (1)
            
            // Call completion handler
            completion(err)
        }
    }

    enum BookError: Error {
         case networkError
         case emptyQuery
         case incorrectBookData([String])
    }

    func getBadData(_ docs: [QueryDocumentSnapshot], _ books: [Book]) -> [String] {
         //...
    }
}
```

Am I correct in assuming this might cause a race condition? If someone can tell me the sequence of how this will execute it'll be a great help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use the snapshot listener to update your local array. This even works when your device is offline.

Comment: @PeterFriese Hey Peter! Love your videos and articles. I do update the local array in my snapshot listener. It's marked with `//<<< (2) Over here!!!`. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've posted, it sounds like there could be a race condition here.

You might want to solve this by making sure the `add` and `get` methods are never executing at the same time. You could use some kind of operation queue for this.